# How to register a global type adapter for an interface, without annotating every class, while using kotlinx.serialization?

Tags: kotlin, gson, kotlinx.serialization

`Gson` would let me do a `GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(MyInterface::class.java, MyConcreteClassAdapter())` but I'm unable to to the same with `kotlinx.serialization`

I want to expose only the interface (`ValueInterface`), so I can hide implementation and serialization details. However, that interface is a field to many classes, like `Box`, and I don't want to leak serialization details by annotating every `ValueInterface` field with a `@Serializable(with = SomeDeserializer::class)`

Note that the `ValueObject` has it's own custom serialization.

The following code breaks with `kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Class 'ValueObject' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'ValueInterface'. Mark the base class as 'sealed' or register the serializer explicitly.`.

However when I change the `Box` value type to `ValueObject` instead of `ValueInterface`, it works.

What do I need to change to make it work like `Gson` and be able to have fields of type `ValueInterface`?

```
package kxs

import kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.PrimitiveKind
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.PrimitiveSerialDescriptor
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.SerialDescriptor
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Decoder
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Encoder
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Test

class KXSTest {

    @Test
    fun test(){
        val actualStr = Json.encodeToString(Box("name1",ValueInterface.create(42)))
        Assert.assertEquals("""{"name":"name1","value":42}""",actualStr)

        val actualObj: Box = Json.decodeFromString("""{"name":"name2","value":43}""")
        Assert.assertEquals(Box("name2",ValueInterface.create(43)),actualObj)

    }
}

// public stuff
interface ValueInterface {
    fun value() : Long

    companion object {
        fun create(long: Long) =
            ValueObject(long)
    }
}

@Serializable
data class Box(val name: String, val value: ValueInterface)


//internal details not meant to be exposed
@Serializable(with = ValueObjectAsLong::class)
data class ValueObject(val value: Long): ValueInterface {
    init {
        require(value > 0)
    }
    override fun value(): Long = value
}

object ValueObjectAsLong : KSerializer<ValueObject> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("ValueObjectAsLong",PrimitiveKind.LONG)

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): ValueObject {
        return ValueObject(decoder.decodeLong())
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: ValueObject) {
        encoder.encodeLong(value.value)
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution? I can use Kotlinx only for fields directly as you said by declaring @Serializable, also I have no idea how to do it for lists, I don't want to create two Serializers - one for T object and another for List<T>

Answer (score 0):

To handle serialization of `ValueInterface` fields, just move `@Serializable(with = ValueObjectAsLong::class)` annotation from `ValueObject` class to `ValueInterface`. It's impossible to annotate interfaces with parameterless `@Serializable` but if you provide a value for the `with` parameter, it compiles fine:

```kotlin
@Serializable(with = ValueObjectAsLong::class)
interface ValueInterface { /*...*/ }
```

It's a bit trickier if you need to serialize 3rd party interface.
First of all, you need to define a serializer for the interface, not its implementing class:

```kotlin
object ValueInterfaceAsLong : KSerializer<ValueInterface> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("ValueInterfaceAsLong", PrimitiveKind.LONG)
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: ValueInterface) = encoder.encodeLong(value.value())
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder) : ValueInterface = ValueObject(decoder.decodeLong())
}
```

Then add `@file:UseSerializers(ValueInterfaceAsLong::class)` annotation into all files with declaration of serializable classes using `ValueInterface` field.

Comment: Yes, that works, but has 2 problems: it leaks implementation details and can only be done on my own source classes. What I really need is a way to register a serializer for an interface (which I can't or don't want to modify).

Comment: Actually, implementation details of the interface have already leaked - `create()` method not only uses `ValueObject` class internally but also as its return type (to avoid latter, it should have been declared as `fun create(long: Long): ValueInterface = ValueObject(long)`), so adding annotation referencing serializer for this class is not a big deal. Updated my answer regarding the serialization of 3rd party interfaces.